# adding first 5 characters of a file name to each line in the file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have many ".txt" files in a folder.

For each .txt file, I need to get the first 5 characters in the name of the file and add them to the beginning of each line in file. I also need to add a "*" sign at the start of each line in the new file.

I have tried using the following command, but it gives me erroneous output in those files that have more than one space per line in the file.

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {chr =substr(FILENAME, 0,5); name = FILENAME ".new" }{ printf("%s %s\n", "*"chr$1, $2) >name}' *.txt
```

Can someone modify the code or suggest a simpler method to do this.

Comment: What does "it giving me erroneous output in those files that have more than one space per each line in the file." mean **exactly**? Please [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output, including showing us the error messages or  otherwise undesirable output you're getting.

Comment: You write about modified lines, _"in the new file"_. Are you hoping to create a directory of new files? Or add these new files to the `pwd`? Or something else (e.g. overwrite the current files)? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to only deal with the two first fields of each line when you output the data; just print `$0` (the whole original line) instead:

```bash
awk '
    FNR == 1 { close(name); chr = substr(FILENAME, 3, 5); name = FILENAME ".new" }
    { printf "*%s %s\n", chr, $0 >name }' ./*.txt
```

You may use `print "*" chr, $0 >name` in place of the `printf` statement if you wish.

Alternatively, use a shell loop:

```bash
for name in *.txt; do
    PREFIX=${name:0:5} awk '{ printf "*%s %s\n", ENVIRON["PREFIX"], $0 }' <"$name" >"$name.new"
done
```

Here, I'm assuming that you are using a shell with support for `ksh93`'s `${param:offset:length}` operator such as, `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh`, `mksh`, busybox sh.  With `yash`, use `${name[1,5]}` in place of `${name:0:5}` (also works in `zsh`), or POSIXly: `${name%"${name#?????}"}`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a shell loop to iterate across the files (here assuming a shell that supports the `${param:offset:length}` operator from ksh93):

```bash
for f in *.txt
do
    sed -i -- "s/^/*${f:0:5} /" "$f"
done
```

(assuming file names don't contain backslash, newline or `&` characters).

My preference would be to write the data to a new file and when they're all done then replace them *en masse*. This would allow handling of an interrupted process. But that's not what I've done here.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'for @*ARGS {                                          \ 
                my $str  = .substr(0..4);                         \ 
                my @body = .IO.lines.map({ "*" ~ $str ~ $_ });    \
                spurt($_ ~ "_new", @body.join("\n") ~ "\n" );     \
            };'   *.txt
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -e 'for @*ARGS ->  $filename {                                   \
                my $str  = $filename.substr(0..4);                       \
                my @body = $filename.IO.lines.map({ "*" ~ $str ~ $_ });  \
                spurt($filename ~ "_new", @body.join("\n") ~ "\n" )      \
            };'   *.txt
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. In Raku, `@*ARGS` is the array that holds arguments placed on the shell command-line. Briefly:

- using `for` the `@*ARGS` array is iterated through,
- using `substr` the first 5 characters of each argument (e.g. filename, here either `$_` or `$filename`) are extracted into `$str`,
- each argument (e.g. filename) is converted to an `IO` object and all `lines` are read. Lines are modified such that `*` and `$str` are added at the beginning of each line, and these modified lines are saved into `@body`,
- Output is created via the `spurt()` method, which takes a filepath (i.e. a name for the newly-created file), followed by the modified-text to be written (`@body`), with suitable newlines added.

Sample Input (example file named `fileA`):

```
>TCONS_00000867
>TCONS_00001442
>TCONS_00001447
>TCONS_00001528
>TCONS_00001529
>TCONS_00001668
>TCONS_00001921
>TCONS_00001922
```

Sample Output (`fileA_new`, text modified as required):

```
*fileA>TCONS_00000867
*fileA>TCONS_00001442
*fileA>TCONS_00001447
*fileA>TCONS_00001528
*fileA>TCONS_00001529
*fileA>TCONS_00001668
*fileA>TCONS_00001921
*fileA>TCONS_00001922
```

https://course.raku.org/essentials/positionals/args-array/
https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#@*ARGS
https://docs.raku.org/type/independent-routines#sub_spurt
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

To prepend `"*<first-5-bytes> "` to each line:

```bash
perl -pi -e '$_ = "*" . substr($ARGV, 0, 5) . " $_"' -- *.txt
```

To prepend the first 5 characters instead of bytes, themselves decoded from the bytes of the file's name as per the locale's character encoding:

```bash
perl -MEncode::Locale -MEncode -pi -e '
  $_ = "*".
       encode(locale => substr(decode(locale_fs => $ARGV), 0, 5)).
       " $_"' -- *.txt
```

Or to avoid doing that decode+substr+encode for each line:

```bash
perl -MEncode::Locale -MEncode -pi -e '
  $prefix = "*".
     encode(locale => substr(decode(locale_fs => $ARGV), 0, 5)).
     " $_" if $. == 1;
  $_ = $prefix . $_;
  close ARGV if eof' -- *.txt
```

Would make a difference for a file called `áéíóú123.txt` in a UTF-8 locale for instance.

Using `locale_fs` instead of `locale` would make it work even in some non-POSIX systems where there is such a distinction.